# Meaning of stretch gains

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs

> TOKYO, June 21 (Reuters) - Japanese government bond prices slipped on Thursday, as a lull in China-U.S. trade conflict soothed nerves and curbed investor demand for safe-haven debt. 
>   JGBs were pressured as Japanese stocks **stretched gains** amid the continuing ebb in risk aversion with the Nikkei rising 0.65 percent. [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/japan-bonds/jgbs-dip-amid-lull-in-sino-us-trade-conflict-idUSL4N1TN22U)

Hi, what does "stretched gains" mean here?

When I looked for strentch on Longman, it says:

> [intransitive, transitive] if you make an amount of money, food etc stretch or it stretches, you use less of it than you usually would so that you have it for a longer time [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/stretch)

Does it mean Japanese stocks are using less gains?

Answer (score 2):

It is a different definition. Use [*stretch*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stretch):

> 5. *ergative verb*
>      If an event or activity stretches or is stretched into a further period of time, it continues into that period, which is later than expected.

So it is saying that the (stock market) gains lasted longer than was otherwise expected.